# How to add scrollviewer onto the TabControl header avalonia

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I am trying to create a simple TabControl with dynamic elements that are bound to a var which contains all data needed below is my axaml code which generates the page:

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="using:cmNG.editor.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="cmNG.editor.Views.EditorWindow"
             x:DataType="vm:EditorWindowModel"
             Name="EditorWindowUserControl">
    <UserControl.Styles>
        <Style Selector="Button.Close">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Styles>
    <!-- <TabControl Items="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}"></TabControl> -->
    <TabControl AutoScrollToSelectedItem="True" Items="{Binding FileList}" Name="TabFileControl">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">
                        <!-- <Button Classes="Close" Content="X" Command="{Binding FileClose}"/> -->
                        <Button Background="Transparent" Content="x" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        ToolTip.Tip="Close this tab"
                                        Margin="5 -2 0 0"
                                        Foreground="DimGray"
                                        Padding="5 5 5 5"
                                        Command="{Binding FileClose}"
                                        Grid.Column="1">
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FileName}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

When i add a lot of items they stack the tabs underneath each other as you can see in the following image: [image: Image with TabControl headers]

How do i add a scrollviewer onto the TabControl so i can scroll through the headers without items getting underneath each other?